# XPages are rebuilt automatically when opening designer

Tags: build, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I have a customer who likes to do some basic stuff in Domino Designer in a specific database. He only works with Forms, agents etc and never do any Xpages stuff. I have done all the xpages stuff in the Database.

This morning when I opened designer I can see that almost all of the xpages design object has been signed by him. but he has not opened any of the xpages design objects. (only forms) and have not signed the application.

When I look at the webpage I can see that the designn changes I did from a few days back have disapeared, so I seem to be looking at an older version of my webpage.

If I go in to the application and Build the application with my id everything is back to normal.

This scenario seem to repeat only a few times a week even though my customer do changes to the application every day.

Image show the xpages time stamp this morning which seem to be about the same time my customer opened the application in designer.

[image]

Currently we are both using 9.0.1 FP10 but I have also seen this problem before FP10

ps.
Not sure if it is related but my customer also have another version of Domino Designer (8.5.3 Swedish) which he use when signing agents as signing them with v9 cause them to not work.

What can be the cause of this behaviour and how can I avoid it.

thanks

Thomas

Comment: I am pretty sure that it's the 8.5.3 Designer that does the rebuild when opening the database in Designer. This problematic behaviour has been fixed in 9.0.1 (or perhaps in a fix pack release of 9.0.1). See this IBM technote about the problem: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO80591

Comment: thanks Per, that is problably correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that it's the 8.5.3 Designer that does the rebuild when opening the database in Designer. So this happens when the user just wants to sign some agents.

This problematic behaviour has been fixed in 9.0.1 (or perhaps in a fix pack release of 9.0.1). See this IBM technote about the problem: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO80591

Answer (score 6):

Open Designer.  From the top menu, select Project > Build Automatically and ensure it is disabled (not checked).

[image: DDE disable build automatically]

For additional reading, refer to Nathan T. Freeman's wonderful article "Taming Domino Designer" https://nathantfreeman.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/tamingdesigner.pdf